# How to temporarily add a CSS style?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a `div` and when I mouse over it I want to change the background (and possibly other properties). I can do it by calling `el.style.backcolor = ""`, but is there a way I can add another CSS style to it then remove it later? Like `style += mouseOverStyle` and then `style -= mouseOverStyle`. That way I could select the properties to change in the CSS instead of in the JavaScript code.

EDIT: I may want to apply the new style in other situations, not just mouseover, so #div:hover isn't really a general solution. What I'm really asking is is there something like style.add("style") and style.remove("style")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add or remove CSS classes when needed.

Adding:

```
yourElement.classList.add('my_class');
```

Removing:

```
yourElement.classList.remove('my_class');
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: That's what I want to do - how? (I've only just started css/javascript)

Comment: But what if the element in ASP.net has a Style="" property? The class does not override the style

Answer (score 6):

If I understood you correctly, you're asking to change the background when you hover your div element?

This is easily done via CSS, no Javascript or other codes are necessary!

```
#myDiv
{
   background-color: #f00;
}

#myDiv:hover
{
   background-color: #00f;
}
```

Of course you can change other styles too, you don't need to add another class to change one or more styles.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: +1: good answer. There's absolutely no need to use Javascript for a mouse over / hover event.

Comment: I remember something of this not being possible in all browser (notoriously IE: http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html).

Comment: minor typo error on #myDiv{ background.color }, I think you mean background-color?

Comment: I sure did mean that! thanks :) @Kooilnic: I've never had a problem with it, only IE6 can't hover on anything but an anchor (afaik) and IE6 should be ignored.

Comment: I would accept this as the answer, but see my edit. I need it for things other than just mouseover.

Comment: Now I don't understand, you can add any CSS attribute to these hover styles. You need it for other things than mouseover? Please give an example :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using multiple :hover pseudo selectors:

```
div.style1:hover { background: red }
div.style2:hover { background: yellow }
```

Then use javascript/jquery to switch between html class attributes

Answer (score 0):

I would recomendate you to use a JS library, such as jQuery. In jQuery it is simple like that:
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ together with the mouseover event handling http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/.

Comment: thats adding bloatware for something extremely simple :-P

Comment: @Antwan usually, once you add a library like jQuery, you will easily find more than one use for it. I don't think anybody should use JS without a library these days.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeStyle()
{
   document.getElementById("elementID").style.color="green";
 }
```

after the .style. you should paste the css attribute you want to edit.

Comment: I'd like to control the properties in css.

Comment: @dan gibson you can change a lot of properties this way, like background, border, float you name it

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use js, change the properties on the user event.

```
onmouseover : el.style.background = "blue";

onmouseout : el.style.background = "red";
```

If you want to add more properties as time goes along just throw it in a function

```
function onMouseOverFunction () {
   el.style.background = "blue";
   el.style.color = "blue";
   el.style.font-size= "1em";
}
```